# Unity UI element uses hitbox of children as well as it's own

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am using an Event Trigger component on a UI Button in unity, with the Pointer Enter function that runs when the mouse pointer hovers over the button. However, I have noticed that this function also runs when I hover over what the colliders of the children would be, even though there are no box colliders on the child objects. What is going on here?

It's like it is using compound colliders even though I only have a box collider 2D on the parent object, and it is UI.

I am using C#.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for UI you don't need any collider **at all**.

Rather any UI element (on this or child objects) like `Text`, `Image`, etc which has [`RaycastTarget`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-raycastTarget.html) enabled receive the events which will then bubble up until any of the parent object consumes them.